# How to Delete Rows that exceeds max row limit in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset that has a few really really large size rows (JSON data column with over 50MB) which causes my query to break and gives an error

```
API limit exceeded: Message before conversion exceeds max row limit, limit: 20971520 actual: 57329961
```

Is there a way to ignore rows that are too large in size or just drop them within the query? Or perhaps there is a way to extract meta information about rows in a table that i can then use to drop those rows?

Comment: Hi OP, can you please provide a sanitized version of your query that resulted to the above mentioned error message for proper replication of your use case?

Comment: @ScottB You cant replicate it as it depends on the dataset.
```    select id, at_list.element.name as key,at_list.element.value as value from (select * from `table_in_question` 
    ) , UNNEST (attributes.list) as at_list 
```